# Dictionary transformation and counter

Tags: python

Object:

```
data = [{'key': 11, 'country': 'USA'},{'key': 21, 'country': 'Canada'},{'key': 12, 'country': 'USA'}]
```

the result should be:

```
{'USA': {0: {'key':11}, 1: {'key': 12}}, 'Canada': {0: {'key':21}}}
```

I started experiment with:

```
result = {}

for i in data:
    k = 0
    result[i['country']] = dict(k = dict(key=i['key']))
```

and I get:

```
 {'Canada': {'k': {'key': 21}}, 'USA': {'k': {'key': 12}}}
```

So how can I put the counter instead `k`? Maybe there is a more elegant way to create the dictionary?

Comment: Why is it `'Canada': {1: {'key':21}}` instead of `'Canada': {0: {'key':21}}`?

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake. Fixed.

Comment: @vlad post your solution as well so that other can get benefit

Comment: If you're using sequential indexes, and there is only one item in the inner dicts (the key), you should just use a list of keys instead of these nested dicts, and you don't lose any information: `{'USA': [11, 12], 'Canada': [21]}`. That will greatly simplify your code.

Comment: @agf True, but I simplified this example for better understanding (perhaps too much).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I used the `len()` of the existing result item:

```
>>> import collections
>>> data = [{'key': 11, 'country': 'USA'},{'key': 21, 'country': 'Canada'},{'key': 12, 'country': 'USA'}]
>>> result = collections.defaultdict(dict)
>>> for item in data:
...     country = item['country']
...     result[country][len(result[country])] = {'key': item['key']}
... 
>>> dict(result)
{'Canada': {0: {'key': 21}}, 'USA': {0: {'key': 11}, 1: {'key': 12}}}
```

There may be a more efficient way to do this, but I thought this would be most readable.

Comment: `has_key` is deprecated. You should use `if country not in result:`. Also, when you need a default for a dictionary key, you should use a `defaultdict` so the test is done automatically: `result = collections.defaultdict(dict)`.

Answer (score 2):

[@zigg's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9727005/42346) is better.
Here's an alternative way:

```
import itertools as it, operator as op

def dict_transform(dataset, key_name=None, group_by=None):
    result = {}
    sorted_dataset = sorted(data, key=op.itemgetter(group_by))
    for k,g in it.groupby(sorted_dataset, key=op.itemgetter(group_by)):
        result[k] = {i:{key_name:j[key_name]} for i,j in enumerate(g)}
    return result

if __name__ == '__main__':
    data = [{'key': 11, 'country': 'USA'}, 
            {'key': 21, 'country': 'Canada'}, 
            {'key': 12, 'country': 'USA'}]
    expected_result = {'USA': {0: {'key':11}, 1: {'key': 12}}, 
                   'Canada': {0: {'key':21}}}

    result = dict_transform(data, key_name='key', group_by='country')
    assert result == expected_result
```

Answer (score 1):

To add the number, use the {key:value} syntax

```
result = {}

for i in data:
    k = 0
    result[i['country']] = dict({k : dict(key=i['key'])})
```

Comment: This still doesn't give the desired answer

Answer (score 1):

```
dict(k = dict(key=i['key']))
```

This passes `i['key']` as the `key` keyword argument to the `dict` constructor (which is what you want - since that results in the string `"key"` being used as a key), and then passes the result of that as the `k` keyword argument to the `dict` constructor (which is not what you want) - that's how parameter passing works in Python. The fact that you have a local variable named `k` is irrelevant.

To make a dict where the value of `k` is used as a key, the simplest way is to use the literal syntax for dictionaries: `{1:2, 3:4}` is a dict where the key `1` is associated with the value `2`, and the key `3` is associated with the value `4`. Notice that here we're using arbitrary *expressions* for keys and values - not *names* - so we can use a local variable and the resulting dictionary will use the named value.

Thus, you want `{k: {'key': i['key']}}`.

> Maybe there is a more elegant way to create the dictionary?

You could create a list by appending items, and then transform the list into a dictionary with `dict(enumerate(the_list))`. That at least saves you from having to do the counting manually, but it's pretty indirect.